# Does it make sense to combine DFS and BFS in maze solving at the same time

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I was recently solving a maze problem which should check if there is a way from point A to point B:

```
. . . . . . . . . . 
. A . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . _ _ _ _ 
. . . . . . | . . . 
. . . . . . . . B . 
. . . . . . . . . .
```

where in given maze the answer should be `true`. I was considering both `DFS` and `BFS` algorithms. In most cases `BSF` seems to be more efficient.

I am wondering if it makes sense to combine them both:

- spread a few spies - kind of DFS
- start spreading around the spy by running BFS

Would that make sense? Maybe there is an algorithm which follows similar rule?

Comment: Using a DFS to plant spies won't improve the performance of the BFS. It just increases the size of the frontier that the BFS is exploring. Hence, it takes fewer iterations to find the goal, but each iteration has more nodes to check. Overall, there's no improvement.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I would surely choose DFS algorithm and will explain why:

Overall, DFS is faster and requires less memory (when talking about a wide and deep tree), than BFS and other search algorithms. The reason BFS is usually used more is that it finds the **shortest path** to the target (and it's better when a solution is not far from the root). But, as I see, you don't really need it. You just need to know if **there is** a path to the target.

Of course, there are other algorithms, like A-star and Dijkstra, but they are all about improving BFS ability to find the shortest path in less time and space, so they're not for your case.

The combined way you suggested is fine but doesn't make much difference and has a lot of issues to solve- what exact spies to choose? how much to develop each one? I think it would lead to a lot of problems instead of just a clean solution, but of course- it's my own opinion.

Good Luck! Hope it helped :)

Comment: I believe you mixed up DFS and BFS. There is *no* guarantee that **D**FS will find a shortest path, while **B**FS does make that guaranteee.

Comment: Because you will need to keep a collection of visited nodes for both DFS and BFS, their memory usage should be similar. Also, Dijkstra in this case would just be a slower version of BFS, as every "edge" has unit weight. A* would actually often perform better in both time and space than any of the others.